# Unable to connect to Core 2 Identity secured, in-app api using javascript

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a site built in Asp.Net Core 2 MVC that uses Core 2 Identity to secure it. At one point in the app, I'm trying to use reactjs  to pull data from a simple, internal api (but the problem happens when I use plain ole' JS as well, mind you).

In the pre-core days, I would just add an ActionResult method to my controller and return a JsonResult with the data and Bob's your uncle. If I needed it secured, I just added [Authorize] to said method and if the user was logged in, the javascript would fire just fine. No fuss, no muss.

Now, however, that doesn't seem to work any more. Every time I try to connect to the controller (and I've even tried with an APIcontroller as well), the data returned is the HTML for the login page. Here's the weird part, if I point my browser to it manually, it returns the necessary json but the moment I try to access it via javascript it doesn't carry the authentication like it used to.

Yeah, stuff has changed. I get that. The problem is that all the tutorials and tips I've come across so far revolve around securing a standalone API that needs it's own special login routine and so on. Near as I can tell, it doesn't apply to what I'm wanting to do (unless I'm just being dense).

So my question ultimately is: what do I do if the only processes that are ever going to use the api are internal to the site and the user is already logged in to the system and I don't want to have to re-authenticate them in order to connect via javascript? Is there a way to pull the necessary tokens/auth/info/whatever from their existing login or, for that matter, generate it once when they log in and just pass it whenever I need it?

Thanks!

Edit: Admittedly, I wasn't sure what kind of information and code people would need so I was waiting until I got some questions so as not to clutter up with more useless info (compared to the relatively useless info of the original post). That being said, here is the requested code.

### Javascript

```
fetch(invoiceServiceUrl)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

### Controller/Api Code

```
[Authorize]    
public IActionResult GetInvoices()
            {
                var testRecord = new List<InvoiceViewModel>
                                 {
                                     new InvoiceViewModel
                                     {
                                         Id = 1,
                                         InvoiceAmount = "50.00",
                                         InvoiceNumber = "12345WG",
                                         InvoiceDate = "01/01/2018"
                                     }
                                 };

                return Json(testRecord);
```

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
                {
                    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    o.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(100);
                    o.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                    o.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Comment: You have provided a lot of detail without providing important details.Are you using Cookie authentication or token authentication with Identity? you should also show the relevant code, your javascript, and where you have configured authentication in the startup.cs

Comment: also you can still use the authorize tag the same way in .net core 2.0. The fact you are getting redirected to login shows it is working, and that you are not authenticated when sending your request through JS. Why you're not authenticated is difficult to tell without seeing the relevant code

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've edited the original post with the relevant code you asked to see.

Comment: Haven't done much with react. but you need to send your access token with each request, it doesn't seem like you are doing this with your JS request. if authorize works from the browser it suggests your backend is okay. have a look at this similar problem with react https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897364/trying-to-get-then-send-a-cookie-using-react-and-fetch

Comment: Ok, that link you posted fixed the problem. All I had to do was add credentials:"same-origin"} to the fetch command in javascript so the final thing looked like:

fetch(invoiceServiceUrl, {credentials:"same-origin"})
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            });

And it works perfect now. No other changes needed. Not sure how to mark this as solution, though.