# React send cookie to Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, cors, fetch

I need to send cookie in my browser to the Nodejs backend using fetch method. However, the cookie header/value is not displayed in the backend. I am using cors and cookie-parser npm

**React**

```
fetch(baseUrl, {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        authorization: 'Basic ' + secret,
      },
      credentials: 'include'
    }).then((res) => {
      // ...
    })
```

**Nodejs**

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.headers, req.cookies); // no cookie headers
  // some process then return new cookie value
  res.cookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
  return next();
});
```

However, when I use postman to send a request, I can get the cookie value and set new cookie value. Is anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you remove `cookie: document.cookie`?

Comment: It still the same, I cannot receive or set the cookie in the backend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get then send a cookie using react and fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897364/trying-to-get-then-send-a-cookie-using-react-and-fetch)